# how to print 1 to 5 and 5 to 1 using recursion.....?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to print numbers 5-0 then 0-5 in the order with shortest Lines of code. Here's what I implemented. However, looking for any other logic with less number of lines of code. Looking forward for your replies please.
Thanks,

```
            <html>
                <body>  
                    <script>
                    var n;
                    function count(n){
                        console.log(n);
                        if(n>=1){
                            return count(n-1);
                        }
                        else{
                            n=1;
                            count2(n);
                        }
                    }
                    function count2(n){
                        console.log(n);
                        if(n<5){
                            count2(n+1);
                        }
                    }
                    count(5);
                    </script>
                </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: Less number of lines with recursion or without recursion ?

Comment: `[...'12345'].forEach(e=>console.log(e))` for 1 to 5. `[...'54321'].forEach(e=>console.log(e))` for 5 to 1.  with iteration

Comment: @CodeManiac You should post that as an answer mate.

Comment: Be aware that your second function has a hard-coded 5, which will not be "right" when you pass another value than 5 in your main function call. Also, your title describes a sequence without 0, while your question itself and your code include it.

Comment: Depends on what you're really trying to achieve: how about `console.log("12345".split("").join("\n"))`

Comment: Hey @Raghunathreddy G , please post such questions on our sister site [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) as they are off topic on SO. Cheers :)

Answer (score 3):

Your recursive attempt could be written like this:

```js
function count(n, limit=-n){
    console.log(Math.abs(n));
    if (n>limit) count(n-1, limit);
}
count(5);
```

In a non-recursive version it would be:

```js
function count(n) {
    for (let i = -n; i <= n; i++) console.log(Math.abs(i));
}
count(5);
```

Comment: Thank you very much  @trincot

Answer (score 2):

you have no need to use recursion for this. Simply use for loops

```
let number = 5
//from 1 to your desired number
for(let i = 1;i<=number;i++){
    console.log(i);
}
//from your desired number to 1 
for(let i = number;i>0;i--){
    console.log(i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Changing the step:

```
function ctn(num) {
    let i = -1, n = num++;
    do {
        console.log(n);
        n || (i = 1);
    } while ( (n += i) < num);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use iteration. smallest i can think of

```js
console.log('forward');

[...'12345'].forEach(e=>console.log(e));

console.log('reverse');

[...'54321'].forEach(e=>console.log(e));
```

Answer (score 0):

It can take any no., any  increment (inc)

```js
const print = (i=5, flow=1, inc=-1) => {
    console.log(i);
    if(i===0 && flow===1){
        print(i+1,flow+1, 1);
        return;
    }
    if(i===5 && flow===2){
        return;
    }
    print(i+inc, flow, inc);
}

print();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version using **generators** just for the sake of it!

It creates an array from the output and does the console.log all in one go.

```js
function* count(n, max = n) {
  yield n > 0 ? n : -n;
  if (n > -max) yield* count(n-1, max);
}

console.log(Array.from(count(5)))
```